# Cannot define the object because one of the instance attribute is already defined in the child class

Tags: python

**# PolygonBaseClass.py >**

```
class Polygon:
     def __init__(self, no_of_sides):
        self.n = no_of_sides
        self.sides = [0 for i in range(no_of_sides)]
     def inputSides(self):
        self.sides = [float(input("Enter side "+str(i+1)+" : ")) for i in range(self.n)]
     def dispSides(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            print("Side",i+1,"is",self.sides[i])
```

**# TriangleChildClass.py >**

```
from PolygonBaseClass import Polygon
class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__(3)  
    def findArea(self):
        a, b, c = self.sides
        # calculate the semi-perimeter
        s = (a + b + c) / 2
        area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5
        print('The area of the triangle is %0.2f' %area)
```

**Question: How do I define object tri1**

**# triangleObject.py>**

```
from TriangleChildClass import Triangle
*tri1 = Triangle("Tri1",3)*
print(triangle1.inputSides())
print(triangle1.dispSides())
print(triangle1.findArea())
```

Comment: `tri1 = Triangle()`

Comment: As a side note, printing the return value of methods that themselves print and don't return anything is not a very good idea. Your methods should rather return something, that you can choose to print or not after calling them.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob tri1 = Triangle() worked. Thierry I change the prints do returns.